# Why will this code relying on RestSharp run fine in my application when run on Windows 1709 but not 1703

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I had someone build an application that calls home to confirm the user is in good standing on start-up.  When the application is installed on a machine running Windows 1709 I can see the call to the api endpoint when the application starts.  However, when I install on Windows 1703 the application does not ever call home (that is the server shows no contact attempt from the ip address where the installation is occurring).  I have tried to Install an older .Net (4.5.2) but I get a message in Windows that the installation is blocked because a newer version exists on the machine.

The application installs 106.2.1.1

Here is a block of code - I have anonymized the token and the API endpoint

```
class RestRoutines

{

    public bool testToken(string token)

    {

        bool passed = false;



        var client = new RestClient("https://api.myanonymousapi.com/v1/user-tasks/");

        client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", token); // "Token validToken");

        var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());



        if (response.StatusDescription   == "OK")

            passed = true;



        return passed;

    }

}
```

Is there a dependency we are missing or is something wrong with the code above that causes it to fail in the earlier version of Windows?

Comment: Well you must get a response or error or something? What *does* happen? Also, have you considered switching form double spaced lines to single spaced?

Comment: No response - this is packaged in an application

Comment: So it just sits at `var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());` forever? No timeout or anything?

Comment: No it returns `passed = false`  we get an error that indicates the user does not have authorization  But I want to be clear it does not check with the server - firewall all open